# Regex to match single folder in url for web.config URL rewrite

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, web-config

We currently use a rather rubbish regex (evidently) to match usernames after a url to rewrite them to a profile page.

```
<rule name="Profiles" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(?:\w|[-_.])+" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:0}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:0}.php" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/{R:0}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/profile.php?username={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
```

I've just realised this matches way more than is required and broken images / urls are trying to load the profile page too.

I'm after a regex that would match.

```
/myusername
/myusername/
```

Allowing for **alphanumeric and underscores** but not any additional slashes...

E.g. `/qweqwe/qweqwe` would fail.

Comment: You regex does not match slashes. If you need to only match word chars, use `\w+`, use it instead of `(?:\w|[-_.])+`. Probably, you want to also anchor the regex, `^\w+$`.

Comment: Perhaps, you actually just need `"^(?:\w|[-_.])+$"` (or its equivalent `"^[-_.\w]+$"`)?

Comment: Chris, any news? Did the comment above work?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Ok, I suppose the regex gets a string without the initial `/`, so, to match one with an optional trailing `/`, you may try `"^[-_.\w]+/?$"` or a more generic `"^[^/]+/?$"`